# unsigned int vs. size_t for string.lenght()

Tags: c++, string, string-length, size-t

What is the correct way to use str.length() in cpp?

```
string s = "Hello";
int length = s.length();
```

or

```
string s = "Hello";
unsigned int length = s.length();
```

or

```
string s = "Hello";
unsigned int length = static_cast<unsigned int>(s.length());
```

Comment: `auto length = s.length();`? You mention `size_t` in the title, but none of your examples use it, why?

Comment: Somehow, even though it is mentioned in your title, none of your options actually use `size_t`.

Comment: `std::size_t length = s.length();`. Or even better, `std::size_t size = s.size();` for consistency with other containers.

Comment: Depends what you're doing with it and what assumptions you want to make. Do you know the size will always fit in an `int` or `unsigned`? Are you going to be doing some signed arithmetic or comparison with it?

Comment: `auto length = s.length();` or `size_t length = s.length();` is what I prefer, but unless you've got a string with a lenght exceeding the max value of `int`, all those alernatives are ok.

Comment: is there some reason you want an `int` ? If not it isnt clear why you are casting and not using the type that `size()` returns

Comment: Neither.   `std::size_t length = s.length()`  is better, as it is consistent with what `s.length()` *actually* returns.    From C++11, you can do `auto length = s.length()`.    [As an aside, it is usually preferable to use iterators or (from C++11) range-based loops rather than looping using integral indices - which, among other things, means it is rarely necessary to compute `s.length()` (or, equivalently, `s.size()`) at all].

Answer (score 3):

To be pedantic, I would recommend you use `std::string::size_type`. That way, you can't go wrong:

```
std::string s = "Hello";
std::string::size_type length = s.length();
```

You can alias it to a shorter type for brevity if you like:

```
using str_size = std::string::size_type;

std::string s = "Hello";
str_size length = s.length();
```

Of course, you can often let  the compiler figure out the correct type for you using `auto`:

```
std::string s = "Hello";
auto length = s.length();
```

Answer (score 0):

In `c++`, the `std::string` class has a `.size()` method that returns a value of the type `size_t` (by default, anyway. For a better understanding of why this is the type `.size()` returns by default see @bitmask's comment below) which is used to represent sizes (as its name implies). So considering that, your code should look something like

```
std::string s("hello world!");
size_t string_length = s.size();
```

Comment: Technically, `std::string::size()` returns a `size_type` which is aliased to its allocator's `size_type` which in turn for the default Allocator of `std::string`, namely `std::allocator` is then `std::size_t`.

Comment: @bitmask thank you for the elaboration. I'll reference your comment in my answer